# Get access to the class static properties using BabelJS 6

Tags: javascript, babeljs

Below is the minimal app which demonstrate the issue:

```
'use strict';

var _ = require('underscore');

class Model
{
    constructor(value) {
        this._value = value;
    }

    get value() {
        return this._value;
    }

    toJS() {
        return this.value;
    }
}

class ObjectModel extends Model
{
    static properties = {};

    constructor(value) {
        super(_.extend({}, new.target.properties, _.pick(value, _.keys(new.target.properties))));
    }
}

class PostModel extends ObjectModel
{
    static properties = {
        title: 'Hello'
        /* content: '<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>' */
    };
}

console.log(new PostModel({title: 'Nice day', aa: 11, bb: 22}).toJS());
```

It should produce `{title: 'Nice day'}`. Instead it even not compiles. I get this:

```
$ babel app.js
SyntaxError: app.js: 'this' is not allowed before super()
```

I understand why this was done for object properties. But I can't understand why this also was done for class variables.

In BabelJS 5 I used this trick which did the job:

```
class ObjectModel extends Model
{
    static properties = {};

    constructor(value) {
        if (0) { super(); }
        super(_.extend({}, this.constructor.properties, _.pick(value, _.keys(this.constructor.properties))));
    }
}
```

In version 6 it compiles, but when running it produces an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'constructor' of undefined
```

Is there some way to get access to a class static variables before calling `super`? Using something like `init()` instead of a `constructor` is not an option. Maybe creating custom transformation plugin?

System details:

```
$ babel --version
6.2.0 (babel-core 6.2.1)

$ cat .babelrc
{
    "presets": ["es2015", "stage-1"]
}

$ babel-doctor

Babel Doctor
Running sanity checks on your system. This may take a few minutes...

✔ Found config at /path/to/.babelrc
✔ No duplicate babel packages found
✔ All babel packages appear to be up to date
✔ You're on npm >=3.3.0

Everything looks all right!
```

Comment: `new.target.properties`?

Comment: Seems clearer to have the subclass override the constructor and pass in the properties to me, but yeah `new.target` is the way to do this, unfortunately it isn't transpiled by Babel.

Comment: I just check `new.target`. It is workable in Node 5.0 only. Chrome and FireFox show me errors. Also, BabelJS does not converts `new.target` into something ES5. I used `es2015` preset.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was following:

1. Stick to the `new.target` as suggested by [@sjrd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33961570/get-access-to-the-class-static-properties-using-babeljs-6#comment55681955_33961570) and [@loganfsmyth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33961570/get-access-to-the-class-static-properties-using-babeljs-6#comment55683246_33961570):

   ```
   class ObjectModel extends Model
   {
       static properties = {};

       constructor(value) {
           super(_.extend({}, new.target.properties, _.pick(value, _.keys(new.target.properties))));
       }
   }
   ```
2. Create a transpiler which converts all of `new.target` (ES6) into `this.constructor` (ES5):

   ```
   function transpileNewTarget()
   {
       return {
           visitor: {
               MetaProperty(path) {
                   if (path.isMetaProperty() && path.node.meta.name == 'new' && path.node.property.name == 'target') {
                       path.replaceWithSourceString('this.constructor');
                   }
               }
           }
       };
   }
   ```