# babeljs class static in constructor

Tags: javascript, babel-6

The question is how to get access to *class static properties* from within a constructor *before* **super** method was called?

```
class A
{
    constructor(input) {
        console.log('A', typeof new.target);
    }
}

class B extends A
{
    static template = '';

    constructor() {
        console.log('B', typeof new.target);
        super();
    }
}

class C extends B
{
    static template = 'CCC';
}

new C();
```

For some reason I got:

```
B undefined
A undefined
```

instead of

```
B function
A function
```

I've [already asked this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33961570/get-access-to-the-class-static-properties-using-babeljs-6) about a year ago. For now, the solution provided in it is no more workable.

You can try the code in [babel console](http://babeljs.io/repl/#?evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Cstage-0&code=class%20A%0A%7B%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(input)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log('A'%2C%20typeof%20new.target)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20B%20extends%20A%0A%7B%0A%20%20%20%20static%20template%20%3D%20''%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20constructor()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log('B'%2C%20typeof%20new.target)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20super()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20C%20extends%20B%0A%7B%0A%20%20%20%20static%20template%20%3D%20'CCC'%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Anew%20C()%3B%0A). The interesting part is that this code works fine without babel (e.g. in latest Chrome), and when **es2015** checkbox is off.

Comment: This only suggests that there is a Babel bug, not that `new.target` is not working like it did. You should report that `new.target` is not transpiled at all any more, and use an older Babel version for the time being.

Comment: https://phabricator.babeljs.io/T1088

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in babel. I wrote a small plugin that transpiles **new.target**:

https://github.com/vbarbarosh/babel_plugin_transform_es2015_newtarget

```
$ npm install --save-dev git://github.com/vbarbarosh/babel_plugin_transform_es2015_newtarget
$ cat .babelrc
...
    "plugins": ["transform-es2015-newtarget"],
...
```